# How do I allow pointer-events on an HTML5 canvas background while allowing links and buttons to receive pointer-events, too?

Tags: html, canvas, mouseevent

I set an HTML5 `canvas` to a background that looks like interlinked nodes ([link](https://codepen.io/pawelqcm/pen/oxPYox)). The `canvas` element works as expected but when I set it to be the background of the page, I couldn't click on links or buttons on the page.

When I set the `canvas` background to the back of all elements by either declaring a `z-index` value or editing the HTML so that it's the first element, I can normally click on links, but every time a `pointer-event` is active on a button (such as a `hover`) it stops the `canvas` background from getting the mouse pointer's location.

I expect it's got something to do with the `pointer-events`, but I can't move past this because I'm unsure as to what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you put the content of your document in a div `#wrap` with a position absolute over the `canvas`, in order to interact with the particles on canvas you may use the mouse position over the `#wrap`. In your example I'm using `wrap.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler, false);` instead of `canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler, false);`

```js
(function() {

  var canvas, ctx, circ, nodes, mouse, SENSITIVITY, SIBLINGS_LIMIT, DENSITY, NODES_QTY, ANCHOR_LENGTH, MOUSE_RADIUS;

  // how close next node must be to activate connection (in px)
  // shorter distance == better connection (line width)
  SENSITIVITY = 100;
  // note that siblings limit is not 'accurate' as the node can actually have more connections than this value that's because the node accepts sibling nodes with no regard to their current connections this is acceptable because potential fix would not result in significant visual difference 
  // more siblings == bigger node
  SIBLINGS_LIMIT = 10;
  // default node margin
  DENSITY = 50;
  // total number of nodes used (incremented after creation)
  NODES_QTY = 0;
  // avoid nodes spreading
  ANCHOR_LENGTH = 20;
  // highlight radius
  MOUSE_RADIUS = 200;

  circ = 2 * Math.PI;
  nodes = [];

  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  resizeWindow();
  mouse = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (!ctx) {
    alert("Ooops! Your browser does not support canvas :'(");
  }

  function Node(x, y) {
    this.anchorX = x;
    this.anchorY = y;
    this.x = Math.random() * (x - (x - ANCHOR_LENGTH)) + (x - ANCHOR_LENGTH);
    this.y = Math.random() * (y - (y - ANCHOR_LENGTH)) + (y - ANCHOR_LENGTH);
    this.vx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    this.energy = Math.random() * 100;
    this.radius = Math.random();
    this.siblings = [];
    this.brightness = 0;
  }

  Node.prototype.drawNode = function() {
    var color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + this.brightness + ")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 2 * this.radius + 2 * this.siblings.length / SIBLINGS_LIMIT, 0, circ);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  };

  Node.prototype.drawConnections = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.siblings.length; i++) {
      var color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + this.brightness + ")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.lineTo(this.siblings[i].x, this.siblings[i].y);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1 - calcDistance(this, this.siblings[i]) / SENSITIVITY;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  Node.prototype.moveNode = function() {
    this.energy -= 2;
    if (this.energy < 1) {
      this.energy = Math.random() * 100;
      if (this.x - this.anchorX < -ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vx = Math.random() * 2;
      } else if (this.x - this.anchorX > ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vx = Math.random() * -2;
      } else {
        this.vx = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      }
      if (this.y - this.anchorY < -ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vy = Math.random() * 2;
      } else if (this.y - this.anchorY > ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vy = Math.random() * -2;
      } else {
        this.vy = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      }
    }
    this.x += this.vx * this.energy / 100;
    this.y += this.vy * this.energy / 100;
  };

  function initNodes() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    nodes = [];
    for (var i = DENSITY; i < canvas.width; i += DENSITY) {
      for (var j = DENSITY; j < canvas.height; j += DENSITY) {
        nodes.push(new Node(i, j));
        NODES_QTY++;
      }
    }
  }

  function calcDistance(node1, node2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(node1.x - node2.x, 2) + (Math.pow(node1.y - node2.y, 2)));
  }

  function findSiblings() {
    var node1, node2, distance;
    for (var i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node1 = nodes[i];
      node1.siblings = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < NODES_QTY; j++) {
        node2 = nodes[j];
        if (node1 !== node2) {
          distance = calcDistance(node1, node2);
          if (distance < SENSITIVITY) {
            if (node1.siblings.length < SIBLINGS_LIMIT) {
              node1.siblings.push(node2);
            } else {
              var node_sibling_distance = 0;
              var max_distance = 0;
              var s;
              for (var k = 0; k < SIBLINGS_LIMIT; k++) {
                node_sibling_distance = calcDistance(node1, node1.siblings[k]);
                if (node_sibling_distance > max_distance) {
                  max_distance = node_sibling_distance;
                  s = k;
                }
              }
              if (distance < max_distance) {
                node1.siblings.splice(s, 1);
                node1.siblings.push(node2);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function redrawScene() {
    resizeWindow();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    findSiblings();
    var i, node, distance;
    for (i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      distance = calcDistance({
        x: mouse.x,
        y: mouse.y
      }, node);
      if (distance < MOUSE_RADIUS) {
        node.brightness = 1 - distance / MOUSE_RADIUS;
      } else {
        node.brightness = 0;
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      if (node.brightness) {
        node.drawNode();
        node.drawConnections();
      }
      node.moveNode();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(redrawScene);
  }

  function initHandlers() {
    document.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow, false);
    ///////////////////////////////////
    wrap.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler, false);
    ///////////////////////////////////
  }

  function resizeWindow() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function mousemoveHandler(e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
  }

  initHandlers();
  initNodes();
  redrawScene();

})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #25003a;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #25003a;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  line-height: 100vh;
}

#wrap p {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#wrap p a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrap p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="wrap">
<p>
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/">this is a link</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh god it worked! Thank you so much! Now I know how to handle problems like these. Thank you very much again!